# How can I determine if I need to create a wallet?

Tags: cleos

**I asked this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284969/how-can-i-determine-if-i-need-to-create-a-wallet) but I guess this would have been a better place to ask, so I'm reposting**

I'm writing an automation script that creates a wallet when necessary. the problem I have is that `cleos wallet list` gives me an empty result:

> Wallets: []

*even when there is a wallet already in existence*, because (apparently) I need to open it first with `cleos wallet open`

this means that I cannot rely on the list command to tell whether I need to create a wallet. but of course, if I try to open a wallet when none has been created, it fails

so what is the recommended way to determine whether my wallet already exists?

**Addendum I**

I have a similar issue with `cleos get accounts`. see: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/7395

Comment: Does it work properly when you type in `cleos wallet list` in you CLI? I mean without the automation scrypt.

Comment: no.  it comes up empty unless I open the wallet first, as stated.  the problem isn't with the script.  it's a problem with cleos -- it should show wallets when not open.  after all, how are you supposed to know what wallet you might want to open if you can't get a listing?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just look whether the wallet file exists? Each wallet is stored in a .wallet file in a directory specified in the configuration file config.ini. In my case the directory is ~/eosio-wallet.

Comment: that solution is a little more complicated.  I now need to look at the process list to find the running node, see if it was given a parameter for where the wallet should be stored (and if not given then use ~/eosio-wallet as you suggest) and then go look.  the point of having a CLI is it abstracts you from having to do this low-level, error-prone stuff.  form my view cleos should give you a list of wallets regardless of whether you've "opened" anything.  in fact, I should just file a bug against it